# sort the postive and negative numbers to show positive numbers first

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I need to show the positive numbers first and then negative numbers while sorting the numbers in SQL Server 2008.

Ex:
Lets say I have numbers -4,-3,null,2,3
Then expected result : 2,3,-4,-3,null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908147/orderby-in-sql-server-to-put-positive-values-before-negative-values

Answer (score 4):

Based on your small example, it seems that you want the positive numbers in increasing order and then the negative numbers in increasing order.

That makes the problem slightly more interesting.  Try this `order by` clause:

```
order by (case when col > 0 then 2 when col < 0 then 1 else 0 end) desc,
         col asc
```

Here is an example:

```
with t as (select 2 as col union all select 3 union all select -4 union all select -3 union all select null)
select *
from t
order by (case when col > 0 then 2 when col < 0 then 1 else 0 end) desc,
         col asc;
```