# OrderBy in SQL Server with custom "max" integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have table in SQL Server which contains a sort column of integers. All values in the column are positive. I want to sort the table such that I chose a "max" value (like 3) and all values are returned decreasing relative to 3. The "descending" order doesn't actually matter much as long as each item in the database is listed.

Database example:

```
Value SortColumn
A     1
B     5
C     4
D     3
E     0
F     2
```

Desired output (with 3 as "max"):

```
Value SortColumn
D        3
C        4
B        5
E        0
A        1
F        2
```

It seems that this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908147/orderby-in-sql-server-to-put-positive-values-before-negative-values) might be in the right direction, but it's not quite what I want....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
order by abs(sortcolumn - 3) asc
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    Value, SortColumn
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN SortColumn = 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    SortColumn DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested solution by Tim and Gordon but the result is not matching with what you want.

My solution is very long though. have a look:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (Value CHAR,SortColumn INT)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('A',1),('B',5),('C',4),('D',3),('E',0),('F',2)

DECLARE @max INT=3;

;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 1-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortColumn DESC) RN, * FROM @table WHERE SortColumn >=@max 
UNION
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortColumn) RN,* FROM @table WHERE SortColumn <@max
)
SELECT Value,SortColumn FROM CTE ORDER BY RN
```

and output is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort numbers greater than 3 ascending and then numbers less than 3 ascending.  So do this:

```
SELECT 
   -- blah
ORDER BY CASE WHEN SortColumn >= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 DESC, SortColumn ASC
```